# lua with Nginx : bad argument to 'getNewSessionID' (string expected, got nil)

Tags: nginx, lua

I have compiled nginx with Lua. and i am facing a  problem .

When i hit localhost i get an error in nginx error logs

```
    2015/05/29 07:41:32 [error] 112#0: *1 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: /opt/hello.lua:11: bad argument #1 to 'getNewSessionID' (string expected, got nil)
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
    [C]: in function 'getNewSessionID'
```

Nginx configurations are

```
location / {
    default_type   'text/html';
    content_by_lua_file  /opt/hello.lua;
}
```

And my hello.lua look like

```
  package.path = package.path ..';/opt/?.lua'
JSON = (loadfile "/opt/JSON.lua")()
local proxyFunctions = require("proxyCode")
coherenceNGIXLocation = "/coherence"

local coherenceCookie = proxyFunctions.getExistingSessionID()

-- To Create a coherance Session if not present
if (not coherenceCookie  or coherenceCookie == '') then
--  ngx.log(ngx.INFO,"No Coherence Session Exists, Creating New")
  local uidCookieValueEncoded = proxyFunctions.base64Encode(str,proxyFunctions.getNewSessionID())  
  local sessCreateResponse = proxyFunctions.coherencePut('{"sessionToken":"'..uidCookieValueEncoded..'"}')
  local parsedJSON= JSON:decode(sessCreateResponse.body)

  ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "Coherence Session Create")
  ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "\n\n\n=============Coherence Res==============\n\n\n"..sessCreateResponse.body.."\n\n\n=============Coherence Res==============\n\n\n")
end

local client_cookie = ngx.req.get_headers()["cookie"]


-- To Create a coherance Session if not present 
ngx.log(ngx.DEBUG, "\n\n\n=============REQ==============\n\n\n"..proxyFunctions.deepPrint(ngx.req.get_headers()).."\n\n\n=============REQ==============\n\n\n")

-- Set the cookie for the legacy request
ngx.req.set_header('cookie', client_cookie)
ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "\n\n\n=============REQ URI==============\n\n\n"..ngx.var.request_uri.."\n\n\n=============REQ URI==============\n\n\n")

local legacy_res = ngx.location.capture("/app"..ngx.var.request_uri, { share_all_vars = true })

ngx.log(ngx.DEBUG, "\n\n\n=============APP Res==============\n\n\n"..proxyFunctions.deepPrint(legacy_res.header).."\n\n\n=============APP Res==============\n\n\n")

if (legacy_res.status == 302) then
   ngx.redirect(legacy_res.header.Location )
else
  ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "Passing the Page/Layout to Maken")
  local dev_res_encoded = legacy_res.body
  dev_res_encoded = ngx.escape_uri(dev_res_encoded)
  -- ngx.req.set_header('Cookie', ngx.req.get_headers()["cookie"])
  -- ngx.req.set_header("Content-Type", "text/html") -- application/x-www-form-urlencoded -- 'page='..dev_res_encoded
  ngx.req.set_header('cookie', client_cookie) -- maken/render
  -- legacy_res.header('Content-Length', legacy_res.header['Content-Length']);

  local maken_res = ngx.location.capture("/maken/", {method = ngx.HTTP_POST, body = legacy_res.body, share_all_vars = true} )

  ngx.header['Set-Cookie'] = legacy_res.header["Set-Cookie"]
  ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "Sending Back Maken Response to Client/Browser with Cookies from lagacy")
  ngx.say(maken_res.body)
end
```

My proxyCode.lua looks like

```
function _M.getNewSessionID()  
           -- strip the sessionID  length 11 cookie name before putting into the session
  -- return string.sub(ngx.var.uid_set,11)
 return _M.removeCookieSessionPrefixname(ngx.var.uid_set,11)
 end

 function _M.removeCookieSessionPrefixname(cookieName)
  return string.sub(cookieName,11)
 end

  function _M.getIncomingAuthToken()
    local cookie = ngx.req.get_headers()["Cookie"] 

    if (cookie ~=nil) then
      local str =  string.match(cookie,"AuthToken=(.*)$")
       if (str ~= nil) then 
          return string.sub(str,11)
      end 
    end
    return nil
  end
```

Can someone help me why i am getting this error ? i am new to Lua programming. and trying to run legacy application on my laptop.